# gdb does not jump to main

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I have been using remote gdb debugging on ARM Cortex A8 for months without any problem.
Then I changed the init command in order to debug some memory leak from

```
set sysroot <path>
```

to

```
set sysroot <path>
set pagination off
set breakpoint pending on
set logging file gdbcmd1.out
set logging on
hbreak malloc
commands
set $mallocsize = (unsigned long long) $rdi
continue
end
hbreak *(malloc+191)
commands
printf "malloc(%lld) = 0x%016llx\n", $mallocsize, $rax
continue
end
hbreak free
commands
printf "free(0x%016llx)\n", (unsigned long long) $rdi
continue
end
continue
```

After this operation I was unable to debug. gdb connects to remote target, but it looks like it does not increment the PC and it does not break at main().

I restored the previous init command but the problem persists, it looks like something has been corrupted.

This the gdb console:

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) 0xb6fcea00 in ?? ()
Quit
(gdb) break main
Note: breakpoint 24 also set at pc 0x29896.
Breakpoint 25 at 0x29896: file source/main.c, line 326.
(gdb) next
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb)
```

Obviously, when I launch the binary without gdb it works.

Comment: What happens if you do `continue` instead of `next`?

Comment: Thank you ssbssa, with continue I found there still were the breakpoints on free() and malloc() but the debugger was unable to find the entry points (I think because this part of code has been compiled without debugging information). 

Removed these breakpoints the debugger works again. Sorry but I was convincted that once removed the command file also the breakpoints were removed.